# Accepting dynamic JSON object in a jersey serice

Tags: java, json, moxy, glassfish-4, jersey-2.0

I'm new to Java.
In jersey, how can I accept a dynamic object (not bound to a class)?

Example:

```
public class MyResource extends Application {
  @POST
  public String process(??? obj) {
    return obj.get("dynamic_property");
  }
}
```

I thought that maybe a `DynamicEntity` or a `Map` will work, but they didn't.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you might want a json object. Why did you tag your question with json? I'm assuming the property isn't actually "dynamic"

Comment: You can always accept it as a `String` and convert it to a `JSONObject` in whatever implementation you use. That's probably technically better than having the `JSONObject` type directly in the resource method, as you can send back responses like `400 Bad Request` if you get a non-JSON string.

Comment: Yes the service accepts a JSON object, but I want to parse it dynamically - without mapping it to a class.

Comment: @ChrisHayes but isn't there a way to achieve this without the boilerplate that parses the string?

Comment: @IgorS. You can register an [entity provider](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html) with Jersey to do this. Writing your own looks somewhat complex but I'm sure that common classes like `Map<String, String>` already have implementations out there somewhere. If you use a JSON library like Jackson, you can see if that library provides an implementation as well.

Comment: You realize that virtually any JSON package will parse JSON into individual Maps and Lists, right?  (Though the specific classes vary depending on which JSON package you use.)  You don't *have* to generate a POJO.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I do. But coming from .NET/Ruby/Node background it seems to me weird that there's no out-of-the-box support for this in jersey. Need to get used to java's way.

Comment: Note that the "normal" way in Java would be to parse JSON to Maps/Lists.  However, folks have become so enamored of Jackson, et al (and some REST packages enthrone that bias), that many folks don't know what's normal any more.